# GeoDistance - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5

I have a problem with the search for GeoDistance in Elasticsearch.

I have in my documents the latitude and longitude of the users according to the Zip code.
With that, I had to include in my system the autocomplete of google addresses to be able to search for a user closer to the given address and I added a radius bar, where I need to inform that I want users close to that address in up to X KM of distance.

The problem is, if I search for a more precise address, with street name, elastic normally finds the user.

But if I enter a more general address, such as a city or country, the search returns nothing.
I believe it has something to do with the search radius, but I haven't found a solution for that.

Here is my code:

```
if (filters.Latitude! = null && filters.Longitude! = null)
{
      //filtros.RangeLogradouro = 20 Km

      andQuery & = queryBuilder.GeoDistance (b => b
                    .Distance (Distance.Kilometers (filters.RangeLogradouro))
                    .Field (p => p.Location)
                    .Boost (1.1)
                    .ValidationMethod (GeoValidationMethod.IgnoreMalformed)
                    .Location (new GeoLocation (latitude: filters.Latitude, longitude: filters.Longitude))
      );
}
```

Has anyone experienced this problem and managed to solve it?

Thank you.